# Working with dynamic regex value in dart & flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

Sometimes we want to implement validation dynamically while taking input from the users. This means you want to store the regex somewhere in the DB & want to add/update the validation accordingly and get it in the API response. But right now, this is not possible:

```
final regex = new RegExp(r'${regex_value}'); // will raise error
```

So what can be the solution to work with dynamic regex?

Answer (score 0):

So to work with dynamic regex, we can do this - get the base64 encoded value of regex from the server/Backend/DB and decode it like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final base64Decoder = base64.decoder;
  const base64Bytes = 'XlxkezAsM30oPzpbLixdXGR7MSwyfSk/JA==';
  final decodedBytes = base64Decoder.convert(base64Bytes);
  print( utf8.decode(decodedBytes) );
  final regex = RegExp(utf8.decode(decodedBytes));
  print( regex.hasMatch('111.2') );
  print( regex.hasMatch('111.22') );
  print( regex.hasMatch('111.222') );
  print( regex.hasMatch('111.') );
}
```